# transparent background with 1px borders?

Tags: html, css, transparency

Is it possible to have a div tag that has 1px black borders and a transparent background, so only the borders are showing?  is this possible?  Any examples?

A really appreciate it.

Erik

Comment: What have you tried? Surly not 'borders:1px solid black;' or similar? You may need to force the width/height if it's empty (or it will be 0x0 and not very easy to spot! If a background color/image is not specified it should be transparent down the parent element(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS:

```
div.emptybox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="emptybox">
Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: transparent background is the default, but the above makes it explicit

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible.

```
#someDiv { border:1px solid #000; }

<div id="someDiv">The div must either have some content, or else have the height and width specified in the CSS above.</div>
```